# Why steady clock is measuring zero in release mode?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to compare two methods of computing the value of PI, one sequential and another one parallel, and measuring the difference between them with a steady clock. When I run them in debug mode, everything works fine, the output is comparable for the two methods:

```
sequential: 2238223
parallel: 506050
```

The problem I am facing is that when I am compiling in release mode, the `steady_clock` does not measure any time difference for the sequential version:

```
sequential: 0
parallel: 271027
```

Another strange thing is that I am printing the values, and at the end of the test I am printing the value of pi returned by the two methods, and the console is immediately printing 0 for the sequential method, after the launch of the program, then it's waiting a while until printing the result of the parallel method, and then **it's waiting a while more** until it prints the result of the pi values, which makes me think that the program is executing the first method right when the value of `pi` needs to be printed.

Is my guess right, then why does the program has this different behavior?

This is the code for the two methods:

```
double ComputePIParallel()
{
    long long i;
    double area = 0;
    double h = 1.0 / n;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(n, h) reduction(+:area) 
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        double x = h * (i - 0.5);
        area += (4.0 / (1.0 + x*x));
    }
    double pi = h * area;
    return pi;
}

double ComputePISequntial()
{
    long long i;
    double area = 0;
    double h = 1.0 / n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        double x = h * (i - 0.5);
        area += (4.0 / (1.0 + x*x));
    }
    return h * area;
}
```

and the main method:

```
int main()
{
    steady_clock::time_point begin = steady_clock::now();
    double pi1 = ComputePISequntial();
    steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();
    long long duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin).count();

    cout<<"sequential: "<<duration<<endl;

    begin = steady_clock::now();
    double pi2 = ComputePIParallel();
    end = steady_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin).count();

    std::cout<<"parallel: "<<duration;

    std::cout<<endl<<pi1<<endl<<pi2;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The value of `n` is `100000000` and it is a global. The code is compiled with MS compiler from Visual Studio 2012, and it has enabled Open MP support.

Comment: maybe compiler figure out `ComputePISequntial` can be done in compile time?

Comment: Maybe the compiler is smart and figured out that `ComputePISequntial` is independent of runtime values and can therefore be computed at compile time. Check the assembler code generated ([here](https://godbolt.org/) for example) and see if it just got optimized out completely.

Comment: Either the compiler computed it at compile time or it noticed you never use the result and just optimized it away.  Best way to know is to check the assembly.

Comment: ..or try print the result along witth first duration